# Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] in Java application

Tags: java, ojdbc

I have the ojbcd8.jar, and I want to use it locally in my gradle project, which is being developed in intelliJ.

I added the jar to my project as follows :

[image]

And I also have the following line in my build.gradle dependencies :

```
compile files('libs/ojdbc8.jar')
```

But, when I try to run my application, I get this error :

```
Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
```

How do I remedy this?

Comment: That is a very old jar isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. It is the only one we are approved for from higher up.

Comment: You ask similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149794/failed-to-load-driver-class-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-in-either-of-hikaric

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself, posting it here in case anybody needs it later :

Enable local Maven repository in the build.gradle file:

```
repositories {  
    mavenCentral()  
    mavenLocal()  
}
```

then install the jar :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
Check that you have the jar installed into your ~/.m2/ local Maven repository
```

Now, add it to the dependencies in gradle!

```
dependencies {  
    compile ("com.oracle:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1")  
}
```

Done.